# Retrieve Python exception object

Tags: python-3.x

I have a piece of code that I don't control and while running it raises an error. I'd like to capture the value of `exc` object inside the `exc_func` method.

As you can see `exc_func` raises two exceptions, one of which is handled. **What I care about is the value of the `exc` object**, but so far have little luck retrieving it. The value does not exist in `exc_traceback` object and the exception message is not very helpful.

```py
import traceback
import sys


def exc_func():
    try:
        a = 1
        a.length()
    except Exception as exc:
        exc.with_not_existing()
        

def main():
    try:
        exc_func()
    except Exception as exc:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        tb_walk = traceback.walk_tb(exc_traceback)
        # Need this in order to pickle traceback
        tb_summary = traceback.StackSummary.extract(tb_walk, capture_locals=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:
For instance, the `exc` object in main is `AttributeError("'AttributeError' object has no attribute 'with_not_existing'")`. What I really want to see is the `exc` object inside `exc_func`. Just to be clear, I need the `exc` object itself, something like `traceback.format_exc()` is not helpful in my case, due to the nature of the exception (it's a C lib that raises this exception)

Comment: You could put the exception in a list, return that, and then read it from there.

Comment: Also, if you want the `main` function to read the exception, then you shouldn't use `try` and `except` in `exe_func`. Just let it raise, and main will handle the exception

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *I'd like to capture the value of exc object inside the exc_func method* and I can't run this code. Do you mean `exc.args`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo edited the question. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: "it's a C lib that raises this exception" In that case showing Python code is not helpful. Does the intermediate exception even exist as a Python object?

Comment: Does `exc_func` the one you have no control over?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the ```exc``` is actually a string not an ```Exception object``` that's why I want to retrive it.

@Tomerikoo I don't have control over ```exc_func```

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve], or otherwise enough information for us to know what you are actually dealing with.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think the code snippet provided does the job. All I need is to retrive the exception object ```exc``` inside the method ```exc_func```. The implementation details should not matter imo.

Comment: You just said "exc is actually a string not an Exception object". In contrast, the code clearly shows an ``exc`` that *is* an Exception object. The latter is easy to retrieve *if* it is capture by an ``except`` clause as shown, the former might well be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception is raised *during* handling another exception, the initial exception is stored as the `__context__`. It can be extracted when handling the new exception.

```py
try:
    exc_func()
except Exception as exc:
    parent = exc.__context__  # the previously handled exception
    print(type(parent), parent)
```

Note that an exception handler may also explicitly chain exceptions via `__cause__`.

> ## [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions)
>
> [...]
> When raising (or re-raising) an exception in an except or finally clause `__context__` is automatically set to the last exception caught; if the new exception is not handled the traceback that is eventually displayed will include the originating exception(s) and the final exception.

> ## [The raise statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement)
>
> [...]
> The from clause is used for exception chaining: if given, the second expression must be another exception class or instance, which will then be attached to the raised exception as the `__cause__` attribute (which is writable).
> [...]
> A similar mechanism works implicitly if an exception is raised inside an exception handler or a finally clause: the previous exception is then attached as the new exception’s `__context__` attribute: